# Need help to regex a text combined from 2 pages

Tags: .net, regex

I need to regex two elements from each row:

- first element to capture is the first 9 digits
- second element to capture is the last 7 digits or the 6 digits -A group

I managed to find a pattern that works for almost everything:

```
(\d{9}).*\r?\n?.*\s(\d{6}-A|\d{7})
```

The text to regex is

```
148016648 1 0.1 Ramburs Mircea Marean, Bistrita RO Bistrita Express S 168 Lei 1017484

148020832 1 0.1 Ramburs Marius Lavaros, Vicovu de RO Vicovu De Express S 299 Lei Sus 1017486 Sus

148026795 1 0.1 Ramburs Laura Marius, Constanta RO Constanta Express S 94 Lei 1017494

148029363 1 0.1 Ramburs Romeo Spaise, RO Deva Express S 629 Lei Deva 033113-A148031835 1 0.1 Cristian Poppescu, Bucuresti RO Bucuresti Express S 1017488

148026795 1 0.1 Ramburs Laura Marius, Constanta RO Constanta Express S 94 Lei 1017494
```

Problem is that when I transform the pdf to text, the last row from the end of each page and the beginning of the next, is combined like this example

```
148029363 1 0.1 Ramburs Romeo Spaise, RO Deva Express S 629 Lei Deva 033113-A148031835 1 0.1 Cristian Poppescu, Bucuresti RO Bucuresti Express S 1017488
```

My pattern doesn't work for these groups. I need help in finding the pattern that identifies that last row into 2 groups.

I use a .NET regex, so need the pattern to work with http://regexstorm.net

Thanks

Comment: It seems `(\d{9}).*?(\d{6}-A|\d{7})` matches these strings in a way you want.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to match from the problem line?

Comment: It maches 148029363 1 0.1 Ramburs Romeo Spaise, RO Deva Express S 629 Lei Deva 033113-A148031835 1 0.1 Cristian Poppescu, Bucuresti RO Bucuresti Express S 1017488 as just one match. It needs to be 2 matches.

Comment: Can anyone help me?